# Mongoose update same column with different values in single query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a mongoose query that modify two records at once but with different updated value.

Scenario: Increase User A's balance while decrease User B's balance.

Any idea???

Comment: Try adding some query which you already tried and need help to further refine it.

Comment: User.update({
    $or: [
      { _id: fromId },
      { _id: toId }
    ],
  }, {
    $inc: { balance: amount  }
  }).exec();

this is as far as I could